# Display Form result in a block

Tags: forms, blocks

I have created a custom form in Drupal 7 and entered some values then submit the form. I want to display the submitted value in a block. How to do this in drupal 7. I am new to this.

This is the code for my custom module

```
function myForm_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['examples/form-example'] = array( //this creates a URL that will call this form at "examples/form-example"
    'title' => 'Example Form', //page title
    'description' => 'A form to mess around with.',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form', //this is the function that will be called when the page is accessed.  for a form, use drupal_get_form
    'page arguments' => array('myForm_form'), //put the name of the form here
    'access callback' => TRUE
  );

  return $items;
}

function myForm_form($form, &$form_state) {

 $form['Value1'] = array(
    '#title' => 'Value 1',
    '#type' => 'textfield', //you can find a list of available types in the form api
    '#size' => 10,
    '#maxlength' => 10,
    '#required' => TRUE, //make this field required 
  );

 $form['Value2'] = array(
    '#title' => 'Value 2',
    '#type' => 'textfield', //you can find a list of available types in the form api
    '#size' => 10,
    '#maxlength' => 10,
    '#required' => TRUE, //make this field required 
  );

 $form['Value3'] = array(
    '#title' => 'Value 3',
    '#type' => 'textfield', //you can find a list of available types in the form api
    '#size' => 10,
    '#maxlength' => 10,
    '#required' => TRUE, //make this field required 
  );
 $form['Value4'] = array(
    '#title' => 'Value 4',
    '#type' => 'textfield', //you can find a list of available types in the form api
    '#size' => 10,
    '#maxlength' => 10,
    '#required' => TRUE, //make this field required 
  );

  $form['submit_button'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Click Here!'),
  );

  return $form;
}

/*function myForm_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  if (!($form_state['values']['Value1'] > 0)){
    form_set_error('price', t('Price must be a positive number.'));
  }
}*/

function myForm_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
    //print($_POST['Value1']);
    //print($_POST['Value2']);
    //print($_POST['Value3']);
    //print($_POST['Value4']);



    drupal_set_message('' . print_r($form_state['values'], TRUE) . '');
    // php

$myurl='http://www.example.com/php/fabric/example.php';
$headers = array('Content-Type: multipart/form-data');
$ch = curl_init($myurl);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
//curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_NOBODY,$data_string);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, true);/*
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data))
);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);*/
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$obj = json_decode($response);
 $count = count((array)$obj);
  $count_MACHINES=  count($obj->MACHINES);
  //echo $count_count;
  for($i=0;$i<$count_MACHINES;$i++)
  {?>
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="cont" name="weavingMachine[]" value="<?php echo $obj->MACHINES[$i];?>"><?php echo $obj->MACHINES[$i];?><br/><?php

                            }
curl_close($ch);


}
```

Comment: where have you saved the form data?

Comment: try looking for hook_block_info() and hook_block_view() on google along with drupal.

Comment: For example if you save data in user, you can use $user. You saved form in custom table then you can query database to fetch the data and use hook_block_view() to render it.

Comment: It would help if you could edit your question and include some of the code you already have. Then we can give you a more detailed answer.